# How to change a CMake file to produce a dll instead of static lib?

Tags: visual-c++, dll, cmake, rtp

I am working on a project where I have to use JRTP (Jori Real Time Tranfer Protocol) library. I m using the version 3.9.1 of the library. When I tried to compile that library I used the following CmakeLists.txt file. But It produces some errors like

```
C:/Program Files/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/GenerateExportHeader.cmake:339 (get_property): get_property could not find TARGET jrtplib}.  Perhaps it has not yet been created.
error PRJ0019: A tool returned an error code from "Building Custom Rule C:/projects/jrtplib-3.9.1/CMakeLists.txt"
```

But I want it to produce dll(dynamic link library). What change I have to make in that file? And what I have to do in Visual studio after building the project?

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)

project(jrtplib)
set(VERSION 3.9.1)

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake")

set (_DEFAULT_LIBRARY_INSTALL_DIR lib)
if (EXISTS "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib32/" AND CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P EQUAL 4)
    set (_DEFAULT_LIBRARY_INSTALL_DIR lib32)
elseif (EXISTS "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib64/" AND CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P EQUAL 8)
    set (_DEFAULT_LIBRARY_INSTALL_DIR lib64)
endif ()

set(LIBRARY_INSTALL_DIR "${_DEFAULT_LIBRARY_INSTALL_DIR}" CACHE PATH "Library installation directory")
if(NOT IS_ABSOLUTE "${LIBRARY_INSTALL_DIR}")
    set(LIBRARY_INSTALL_DIR "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/${LIBRARY_INSTALL_DIR}")
endif()

include(CheckCXXCompilerFlag)
include(CheckIncludeFile)
include(CheckIncludeFileCXX)
include(CheckCXXSourceCompiles)
include(TestBigEndian)
include(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/Macros.cmake)


find_package(JThread)

set(JRTPLIB_LINK_LIBS "")
set(JRTPLIB_INTERNAL_INCLUDES "")
set(JRTPLIB_EXTERNAL_INCLUDES "")

add_additional_stuff(JRTPLIB_EXTERNAL_INCLUDES JRTPLIB_LINK_LIBS)
add_library(jrtplib ${MODULE} ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)
GENERATE_EXPORT_HEADER( jrtplib} 
         BASE_NAME jrtplib
         EXPORT_MACRO_NAME jrtplib_EXPORT
         EXPORT_FILE_NAME jrtplib_Export.h
         STATIC_DEFINE jrtplib_BUILT_AS_STATIC
jrtplib_support_option("Support SDES PRIV items" JRTPLIB_SUPPORT_SDESPRIV RTP_SUPPORT_SDESPRIV ON "// No support for SDES PRIV items")
jrtplib_support_option("Support the probation mechanism for a new source" JRTPLIB_SUPPORT_PROBATION RTP_SUPPORT_PROBATION ON "// Do not wait for a number of consecutive packets to validate source")
jrtplib_support_option("Support sending RTCP APP packets" JRTPLIB_SUPPORT_SENDAPP RTP_SUPPORT_SENDAPP ON "// No direct support for sending RTCP APP packets")
jrtplib_support_option("Support sending unknown RTCP packets" JRTPLIB_SUPPORT_RTCPUNKNOWN RTP_SUPPORT_RTCPUNKNOWN OFF "// No support for sending unknown RTCP packets")
jrtplib_support_option("Support memory management mechanism" JRTPLIB_SUPPORT_MEMORYMGMT RTP_SUPPORT_MEMORYMANAGEMENT ON "// No memory management support")

jrtplib_include_test(sys/filio.h RTP_HAVE_SYS_FILIO "// Don't have <sys/filio.h>")
jrtplib_include_test(sys/sockio.h RTP_HAVE_SYS_SOCKIO "// Don't have <sys/sockio.h>")
jrtplib_include_test(ifaddrs.h RTP_SUPPORT_IFADDRS "// No ifaddrs support")

if (JTHREAD_FOUND)
    set(V "ON")
else (JTHREAD_FOUND)
    set(V "OFF")
endif (JTHREAD_FOUND)

option(JTHREAD_ENABLED "Thread support" ${V})
if (JTHREAD_ENABLED)
    set (RTP_SUPPORT_THREAD "#define RTP_SUPPORT_THREAD")
    if (JTHREAD_FOUND)
        save_paths(JRTPLIB_EXTERNAL_INCLUDES "${JTHREAD_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
        save_paths(JRTPLIB_LINK_LIBS "${JTHREAD_LIBRARIES}")
    endif(JTHREAD_FOUND)
else (JTHREAD_ENABLED)
    set (RTP_SUPPORT_THREAD "// No support for JThread was enabled")
endif (JTHREAD_ENABLED)

if (CMAKE_CROSSCOMPILING)
    option (JRTPLIB_USE_BIGENDIAN "Target platform is big endian" ON)
    if (JRTPLIB_USE_BIGENDIAN)
        set(RTP_ENDIAN "#define RTP_BIG_ENDIAN")
    else (JRTPLIB_USE_BIGENDIAN)
        set(RTP_ENDIAN "// Little endian system")
    endif (JRTPLIB_USE_BIGENDIAN)
else (CMAKE_CROSSCOMPILING)
    test_big_endian(JRTPLIB_BIGENDIAN)
    if (JRTPLIB_BIGENDIAN)
        set(RTP_ENDIAN "#define RTP_BIG_ENDIAN")
    else (JRTPLIB_BIGENDIAN)
        set(RTP_ENDIAN "// Little endian system")
    endif (JRTPLIB_BIGENDIAN)
endif (CMAKE_CROSSCOMPILING)

jrtplib_test_feature(socklentest RTP_SOCKLENTYPE_UINT TRUE "// socklen_t is 'int'")
jrtplib_test_feature(ipv4mcasttest RTP_SUPPORT_IPV4MULTICAST FALSE "// No IPv4 multicasting support")
jrtplib_test_feature(salentest RTP_HAVE_SOCKADDR_LEN FALSE "// No sa_len member in struct sockaddr")
jrtplib_test_feature(getloginrtest RTP_SUPPORT_GETLOGINR FALSE "// Not using getlogin_r")
jrtplib_test_feature(ipv6test RTP_SUPPORT_IPV6 FALSE "// No IPv6 support")
jrtplib_test_feature(ipv6mcasttest RTP_SUPPORT_IPV6MULTICAST FALSE "// No IPv6 multicasting support")

check_cxx_source_compiles("#include <stdint.h>\n#include <sys/types.h>\nint main(void) { size_t a = 0 ; size_t b = a; uint32_t x = 0; uint32_t y = x; return 0; }" JRTPLIB_STDINT)
if (JRTPLIB_STDINT)
    set(RTP_INTTYPE_HEADERS "#include <stdint.h>\n#include <sys/types.h>")
else (JRTPLIB_STDINT)
    check_cxx_source_compiles("#include <inttypes.h>\n#include <sys/types.h>\nint main(void) { uint32_t x = 0; uint32_t y = x; return 0; }" JRTPLIB_INTTYPES)
    if (JRTPLIB_INTTYPES)
        set(RTP_INTTYPE_HEADERS "#include <inttypes.h>\n#include <sys/types.h>\n")
    else (JRTPLIB_INTTYPES)
        if (NOT UNIX AND WIN32)
            set(RTP_INTTYPE_HEADERS "#include \"rtptypes_win.h\"")
        else (NOT UNIX AND WIN32)
            set(RTP_INTTYPE_HEADERS "#error Could not find header files that define types like 'uint32_t'. Please edit the file ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/src/rtptypes_unix.h and make sure that the following types are defined: int8_t, uint8_t, int16_t, uint16_t, int32_t, uint32_t, int64_t, uint64_t")
            message("\n\nError: Could not find header files that define types like 'uint32_t'.\nPlease edit the file ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/src/rtptypes_unix.h\nand make sure that the following types are defined: \nint8_t, uint8_t, int16_t, uint16_t, int32_t, uint32_t, int64_t, uint64_t\n\n")
        endif (NOT UNIX AND WIN32)
    endif (JRTPLIB_INTTYPES)
endif (JRTPLIB_STDINT)

if (NOT UNIX AND WIN32)
    set(RTP_WINSOCK_HEADERS "#if defined(WIN32) || defined(_WIN32_WCE)\n    #include <winsock2.h>   \n  #include <ws2tcpip.h>\n#ifndef _WIN32_WCE\n #include <sys/types.h>\n#endif // _WIN32_WCE\n#endif // WIN32 || _WIN32_WCE\n")
endif (NOT UNIX AND WIN32)

if (NOT UNIX)
    set(JRTPLIB_COMPILE_STATIC ON CACHE BOOL "Flag indicating if a static library should be built, or a dynamic one")
    list(APPEND JRTPLIB_LINK_LIBS "ws2_32")
endif (NOT UNIX)

if (UNIX OR JRTPLIB_COMPILE_STATIC)
    set(JRTPLIB_IMPORT "")
    set(JRTPLIB_EXPORT "")
else (UNIX OR JRTPLIB_COMPILE_STATIC)
    set(JRTPLIB_IMPORT "__declspec(dllimport)")
    set(JRTPLIB_EXPORT "__declspec(dllexport)")
endif (UNIX OR JRTPLIB_COMPILE_STATIC)

configure_file("${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/rtptypes.h.in" "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/src/rtptypes.h")
configure_file("${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/rtpconfig.h.in" "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/src/rtpconfig.h")

save_paths(JRTPLIB_INTERNAL_INCLUDES "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src" "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/src")

add_subdirectory(src)
add_subdirectory(examples)

if (UNIX)
    get_target_property(JRTPLIB_LOCAL_LIBRARY_NAME jrtplib-shared LOCATION)
    get_filename_component(JRTPLIB_LIBNAME "${JRTPLIB_LOCAL_LIBRARY_NAME}" NAME)
    set(JRTPLIB_LIBS "${LIBRARY_INSTALL_DIR}/${JRTPLIB_LIBNAME}")
else (UNIX)
    if (JRTPLIB_COMPILE_STATIC)
        get_target_property(JRTPLIB_LOCAL_LIBRARY_NAME jrtplib-static RELEASE_LOCATION)
        get_filename_component(JRTPLIB_LIBNAME_RELEASE "${JRTPLIB_LOCAL_LIBRARY_NAME}" NAME_WE)
        get_target_property(JRTPLIB_LOCAL_LIBRARY_NAME jrtplib-static DEBUG_LOCATION)
        get_filename_component(JRTPLIB_LIBNAME_DEBUG "${JRTPLIB_LOCAL_LIBRARY_NAME}" NAME_WE)
    else (JRTPLIB_COMPILE_STATIC)
        get_target_property(JRTPLIB_LOCAL_LIBRARY_NAME jrtplib-shared RELEASE_LOCATION)
        get_filename_component(JRTPLIB_LIBNAME_RELEASE "${JRTPLIB_LOCAL_LIBRARY_NAME}" NAME_WE)
        get_target_property(JRTPLIB_LOCAL_LIBRARY_NAME jrtplib-shared DEBUG_LOCATION)
        get_filename_component(JRTPLIB_LIBNAME_DEBUG "${JRTPLIB_LOCAL_LIBRARY_NAME}" NAME_WE)
    endif (JRTPLIB_COMPILE_STATIC)
    set(JRTPLIB_LIBS optimized "${LIBRARY_INSTALL_DIR}/${JRTPLIB_LIBNAME_RELEASE}.lib" 
                 debug "${LIBRARY_INSTALL_DIR}/${JRTPLIB_LIBNAME_DEBUG}.lib")
endif (UNIX)

set(JRTPLIB_INCDIRS ${JRTPLIB_EXTERNAL_INCLUDES} ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/include)
set(JRTPLIB_LIBS ${JRTPLIB_LIBS} ${JRTPLIB_LINK_LIBS})
remove_empty(JRTPLIB_INCDIRS)
list(REMOVE_DUPLICATES JRTPLIB_INCDIRS)
remove_empty(JRTPLIB_LIBS)

foreach(ARG ${JRTPLIB_LIBS})
    set(JRTPLIB_LIBS_CMAKECONFIG "${JRTPLIB_LIBS_CMAKECONFIG} \"${ARG}\"")
endforeach()
foreach(ARG ${JRTPLIB_INCDIRS})
    set(JRTPLIB_INCDIRS_CMAKECONFIG "${JRTPLIB_INCDIRS_CMAKECONFIG} \"${ARG}\"")
endforeach()

configure_file("${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/JRTPLIBConfig.cmake.in" "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/cmake/JRTPLIBConfig.cmake")
install(FILES "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/cmake/JRTPLIBConfig.cmake" DESTINATION ${LIBRARY_INSTALL_DIR}/cmake/JRTPLIB)

if (UNIX)
    foreach(ARG ${JRTPLIB_LIBS})
        set(JRTPLIB_LIBS_PKGCONFIG "${JRTPLIB_LIBS_PKGCONFIG} ${ARG}")
    endforeach()
    foreach(ARG ${JRTPLIB_INCDIRS})
        set(JRTPLIB_INCDIRS_PKGCONFIG "${JRTPLIB_INCDIRS_PKGCONFIG} -I${ARG}")
    endforeach()

    configure_file(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/pkgconfig/jrtplib.pc.in ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/pkgconfig/jrtplib.pc)
    install(FILES ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/pkgconfig/jrtplib.pc DESTINATION ${LIBRARY_INSTALL_DIR}/pkgconfig)
endif (UNIX)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have a syntax error there:

```
GENERATE_EXPORT_HEADER( jrtplib} 
         BASE_NAME jrtplib
         EXPORT_MACRO_NAME jrtplib_EXPORT
         EXPORT_FILE_NAME jrtplib_Export.h
         STATIC_DEFINE jrtplib_BUILT_AS_STATIC
```

A '}' after target name and there is no ')'.

Comment: Hi Arrowdodger,Is it the only problem?

Comment: it seems that Alvi_1987 copied from this page:
http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/BuildingWinDLL
which contains the curly bracket typo. That's what I did too. Thanks for the help!